# Objective-C Generic Response Types?

Tags: objective-c, generics

I have a wrapper for an API written in Objective-C that looks ***roughly*** like so:

```
@interface MyAPI : NSObject

- (void)getUsers :(UserRequest*)request :(void (^)(UserResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError;
- (void)getPosts :(PostRequest*)request :(void (^)(PostResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError;
- (void)getOtherStuff :(OtherStuffRequest*)request :(void (^)(OtherStuffResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError;

@end


@implementation MyAPI

- (void)getUsers :(UserRequest*)request :(void (^)(UserResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
>>> NSString *url = "/api/users";

    HTTPClient *client = [[HTTPClient alloc] init];
    HTTPRequest *httpRequest = [[HTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    httpRequest.queryParams = request.toDictionary;

    [httpClient send:httpRequest success:^(HTTPResponse *httpResponse) {
        NSError *error;
>>>     UserResponse *response = [[UserResponse alloc] initWithString:httpResposne.body error:&error];
        if (error == nil) {
            onResponse(response);
        } else {
            APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
            onError(errorResponse);
        }
    }, error:^(NSError *error) {
        APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
        onError(errorResponse);
    }];
}

- (void)getPosts :(PostRequest*)request :(void (^)(PostResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
>>> NSString *url = "/api/posts";

    HTTPClient *client = [[HTTPClient alloc] init];
    HTTPRequest *httpRequest = [[HTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    httpRequest.queryParams = request.toDictionary;

    [httpClient send:httpRequest success:^(HTTPResponse *httpResponse) {
        NSError *error;
>>>     PostResponse *response = [[PostResponse alloc] initWithString:httpResposne.body error:&error];
        if (error == nil) {
            onResponse(response);
        } else {
            APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
            onError(errorResponse);
        }
    }, error:^(NSError *error) {
        APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
        onError(errorResponse);
    }];
}

- (void)getOtherStuff :(OtherStuffRequest*)request :(void (^)(OtherStuffResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
>>> NSString *url = "/api/otherStuff";

    HTTPClient *client = [[HTTPClient alloc] init];
    HTTPRequest *httpRequest = [[HTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    httpRequest.queryParams = request.toDictionary;

    [httpClient send:httpRequest success:^(HTTPResponse *httpResponse) {
        NSError *error;
>>>     OtherStuffResponse *response = [[OtherStuffResponse alloc] initWithString:httpResposne.body error:&error];
        if (error == nil) {
            onResponse(response);
        } else {
            APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
            onError(errorResponse);
        }
    }, error:^(NSError *error) {
        APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
        onError(errorResponse);
    }];
}

@end
```

I've marked with `>>>` the only two lines that change from one method call to another - just the URL and the response type.

Ideally to avoid duplicate code I would like to do something like this:

```
@interface InternalImplementation<RequestType, ResponseType> : NSObject

+ (ResponseType)getAnything :(RequestType)request fromURL:(NSString*)url;

@end

@implementation InternalImplementation

+ (void)getAnything :(RequestType)request fromURL:(NSString*)url :(void (^)(ResponseType *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
    HTTPClient *client = [[HTTPClient alloc] init];
    HTTPRequest *httpRequest = [[HTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    httpRequest.queryParams = request.toDictionary;

    [httpClient send:httpRequest success:^(HTTPResponse *httpResponse) {
        NSError *error;
        ResponseType *response = [[ResponseType alloc] initWithString:httpResposne.body error:&error];
        if (error == nil) {
            onResponse(response);
        } else {
            APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
            onError(errorResponse);
        }
    }, error:^(NSError *error) {
        APIError *errorResponse = [[APIError alloc] initWithError:error];
        onError(errorResponse);
    }];
}

@end
```

This way I could re-write my API with almost no code duplication:

```
@implementation MyAPI

- (void)getUsers :(UserRequest*)request :(void (^)(UserResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
    [InternalImplementation<UserRequest, UserResponse> getAnything:request fromURL:"/api/users" onResponse:onResponse onError:onError]; 
}

- (void)getPosts :(PostRequest*)request :(void (^)(PostResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
    [InternalImplementation<PostRequest, PostResponse> getAnything:request fromURL:"/api/users" onResponse:onResponse onError:onError]; 
}

- (void)getOtherStuff :(OtherStuffRequest*)request :(void (^)(OtherStuffResponse *response))onResponse :(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
{
    [InternalImplementation<OtherStuffRequest, OtherStuffResponse> getAnything:request fromURL:"/api/users" onResponse:onResponse onError:onError]; 
}

@end
```

Unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to get this working. Can it even be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for generics here. Generics in Objective-C are "lightweight." They don't really *do* anything. They're mostly there to help bridge to Swift. (In theory they could provide better warnings about type mismatches in ObjC, but they rarely if ever do.)

Objective-C is duck typed. If something responds to a message, then it can accept that message. It doesn't matter what the "real" type of the object is. You can add a bunch of public methods like `getUsers:...` in order to get good warnings if the caller does something wrong, but `getAnything` can just accept `Request`. It doesn't need to be generic to do that (I'm assuming that `UserRequest` is a subclass of `Request` and `UserResponse` is a subclass of `Response`).

The only tricky thing is that you need to pass the class so you can `init` it. That's no problem:

```
+ (void)getAnythingWithRequest:(Request *)request
                       fromURL:(NSString *)url
                        ofType:(Class)responseType
                       success:(void (^)(Response *response))onResponse
                       failure:(void (^)(APIError *error))onError
```

With that, assuming that `type` has a `initWithString:`, you can just call it:

```
Response *response = [[responseType alloc] initWithString:@"..."];
```

Objective-C is a highly dynamic language. As long as you make sure everything responds to what you expect it to respond to, then it'll all work. There's no reason to add generics unless you intend to bridge this to Swift.

To make things a little nicer, `getUsers:...` etc can require that their success handler be of a more constrained type, and you can then just bridge across to that new type and add the URL string as you like:

```
+ (void)getUserWithRequest:(UserRequest *)request
                    ofType:(Class)responseType
                   success:(void (^)(UserResponse *response))onResponse
                   failure:(void (^)(APIError *error))onError {

    [self getAnythingWithRequest:request
                         fromURL:@"/api/users"
                          ofType:[UserResponse self]
                         success:^(Response *response){onResponse((UserResponse*)response);}
                         failure:onError];

}
```

Comment: Passing in the `ofType` is exactly what I needed to solve this problem. Thanks for the great answer!